# How to add an image on UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

How do i add a small image on a `UINavigationBar` ? It should display in front of the title. Its small and `40X40` pixel in size.

noteL: I don't want to add an `image` to the `background` to add this tiny image. Furthermore this should work for both iOS4 and 5

Comment: possibile duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441945/add-title-and-image-to-navigationbar

Comment: Also, how could i add an image to the back button of the navigation bar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a Navigation bar you can set both right and left buttons like this:

```
UIImage * myIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];

[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:myIcon
    style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(someAction:)]];
```

To the right button just message setRightBarButtonItem

Comment: I would only need an image, not a button.

Comment: How could i add an image to the back button of the navigation bar ?

Comment: Then this should work:


    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:yourImg style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:target action:@selector(someAction:) ];